# VARCHAR para numero

Tags: mysql, varchar

Tenho uma coluna (valor) em MYSQL em varchar, e nela guardo números inteiros ou quebrados, assim:

```
1.1
2
3.99
4.2
2.345
```

Na consulta preciso saber quando um número é (maior ou igual) e (menor ou igual) a esses números guardados no banco, fiz assim:

```
WHERE valor >= :valor1 AND valor <= :valor2
```

Mas não funciona, acredito que isso ocorra por ser um campo varchar, certo? Como transformar?

Answer (score 4):

Bom, isso está descrito em [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

> O tipo para o resultado pode ser um dos seguintes valores:
>
> - BINARY[(N)]
> - CHAR[(N)]
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> - SIGNED [INTEGER]
> - TIME
> - UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

Portanto, você deve usar:

```
SELECT CAST(PRECO AS DECIMAL(5,2)) FROM PRODUTOS
```

Outro exemplo:

```
SELECT DESCRICAO,PRECO FROM PRODUTOS WHERE CAST(PRECO AS DECIMAL(5,2)) BETWEEN 10 AND 50.5
```

Espero ter ajudado!

[Fonte de estudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830509/cast-to-decimal-in-mysql?rq=1)

Comment: Mas dentro do WHERE como ficaria isso?

Comment: Ajustei a resposta :)))))))

Comment: Você pode usar o between ao invés de operadores >= <= :) Facilita na escrita.. :)

Comment: Dê o feedback se sua dúvida foi sanada e marque como correta a resposta caso positivo. :) Isso vai ajudar outros usuários a sanar a dúvida caso seja semelhante a sua.

Answer (score 2):

Referente a integridades dos dados, seria mais interessante mudar o tipo da coluna, para `decimal`, caso tenha dificuldade em fazer isso, faça uma pergunta.

Agora se não pode alterar o tipo de coluna, teremos que usar a função `cast`, da qual altera o tipo do dado da coluna.

Vamos sor que tenha a tabela, a qual já tenha os dados da sua pergunta:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (
  coluna varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Fazendo a consulta:

```
select coluna
  from (SELECT CAST(t.coluna AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) coluna FROM tabela t) a
 where a.coluna >= 2
   AND a.coluna <= 4
```

Estaríamos convertendo a coluna de `VARCHAR`, para `DECIMAL(5,2)`. Coloquei em uma subconsulta para não ficar fazer o `CAST` 2x, mas recomendo usar o `between`.

Segue exemplo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d07d15/1